# Karate Framework setup in VS code - Quickstart

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, karate

In VS code, I don't know how to setup the karate framework using Quickstart. When I pasted the Quickstart code in cmd, i got that there is a build failure and its showing MissingProjectException error
[cmd-Quickstart Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3olj.png)

To setup karate project in vs code I have installed extensions like Karate Runner,Cucumber,etc
Also I have checked the Java and maven installing in my lap in cmd but I couldn't paste the Quickstart(from Karate GITHUB) code in cmd. It's showing error and I couldn't paste the whole command like that. Even though I pasted it one by one its showing not recognized and MissingProjectException error.
I need to know what the mistake is I have been doing? and any other alternative is there to install. Even now zip release also not available it seems.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably issue pasting multiple line of command, like its warning. You can try to type yourself in cmd in one line, removing all `\`.

On the other hand, if the command is really long, you can type `\` to break command into multiple lines, but you'd better type it manually.

Comment: Thank you, i have tired it now i got it.But while running the  example user.feature file i got- command 'karatelabs-karate.run' not found .... like this so what i should do?

Comment: Check your environment variable PATH configuration.

Comment: `karatelabs-karate.run` seems a environment variable is needed in your karate framework. Please check on Karate document about which value you need to set it. And create a new variable in system environment. Any way you can also google it.